# Poisson's equation solution explicitly

Tags: real-analysis, integration, regularity-theory-of-pdes, poissons-equation

How can I write poisson's equation

$\partial_{xx} u = f$

solution in 1d explicitly?

I have seen somewhere I can write
$u(x) = \int^{x}_{0}\int^{y}_{0} f(z) dz dy - \int^{1}_{0}\int^{x}_{0}\int^{y}_{0} f(z) dz dy dx$

in $[0,1]$ ?

and say u is comparable?

How do you get this explicit form?some integration?what regularity does $f$ need?

Comment: Certainly for Riemann integrable $f$, the first term of the purported solution will have second derivative equal to $f$ (to get $-f$, you'll need to negate it) by the fundamental theorem of calculus. The second term of what you've written makes no sense, because $x$ is both the argument of $u$ and used as a variable of integration. BTW, if $u$ is any solution, so is $v(x) = u(x) + ax + b$, and the freedom of choosing $a$ and $b$ lets you fit boundary conditions.

Comment: so what's the solution?

Comment: $u(x) = \int_0^x \int_0^y -f(z) ~dz ~dy + ax + b$, where $a$ and $b$ are chosen to satisfy the boundary conditions. E.g., if you know that $u(0) = 0$ and $u'(0) = 1$, then $a = 1$ and $b = 0$.

Comment: Please specify the boundary conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A complete solution is
$$
u(x) = \int_0^x \int_0^y -f(z) ~dz ~dy + ax + b,
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are chosen to satisfy the boundary conditions. E.g., if you know that $u(0) = 0$ and $u'(0) = 1$, then $a = 1$ and $b = 0$. On the other hand, if you know that $u(0) = 3$ and $u(1) = 7$, then you have
$$
b = 3\\
a =  -\left(\int_0^1 \int_0^y -f(z) ~dz ~dy + 3 \right) + 7.
$$